# How to read from a properties file in Eclipse Java Dynamic Web Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I think I exactly want to do what he does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641962/how-to-use-a-properties-file-in-eclipse-java-dynamic-web-project)

But with me it's a little different. I started with a check whether the file exists:

```
File f = new File("properties.txt");
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

I don't have a folder `/project/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` as described in the other post but my compiled classes are in `/project/build/classes` so I put my properties file there (exactly: in the package-folder of the class where I am accessing the file).

But it still prints `false`. Maybe I am doing it wrong, if so, please tell me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Properties file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285595/reading-properties-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

If your file is on class path or in class folder than just obtain path from the classpath. Dont use relative path with `java.io.File`, it is depend on the current working directory on which you have not control in JAVA code.

You can try like this :

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("properties.txt");
File f = new File(url.getPath());
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

if your file `properties.txt` is inside any package that give relative path in `getResource(...)` function. e.g `getResource("properties\\properties.txt")`.

Comment: I put the file under `/project/build/classes`, and I tried what you were proposing. I get a `NullPointerException` in this line `File f = new File(url.getPath());`. After that, I tried `System.out.println(url.getPath());` and got the exception as well, so it seems that the class can't access the file. Is it misplaced? Or do I have to change like classpath?

Comment: What is the path given in 'getResouce(...)' argument ?? Make sure file is on path you have provided.

Comment: System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 1):

The code to do this is pretty simple. Let's consider that you have a war file named `SampleApp.war` which has a properties file named `myApp.properties` at it's root :

```
SampleApp.war

|

   |-------- myApp.properties

   |

   |-------- WEB-INF

                |
                |---- classes
                         |
                         |----- org
                                 |------ myApp
                                           |------- MyPropertiesReader.class
```

Let's assume that you want to read the property named `abc` present in the properties file:

in `myApp.properties`:

```
abc = someValue;
xyz = someOtherValue;
```

Let's consider that the class `org.myApp.MyPropertiesReader` present in your application wants to read the property. Here's the code for the same:

```
package org.myapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Simple class meant to read a properties file
 * 
 * @author Sudarsan Padhy
 * 
 */
public class MyPropertiesReader {

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     * 
     */
    public MyPropertiesReader() {

    }

    /**
     * Some Method
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     * 
     */
    public void doSomeOperation() throws IOException {
        // Get the inputStream
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("myApp.properties");

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        System.out.println("InputStream is: " + inputStream);

        // load the inputStream using the Properties
        properties.load(inputStream);
        // get the value of the property
        String propValue = properties.getProperty("abc");

        System.out.println("Property value is: " + propValue);
    }

}
```